# Meteor js. How to sum records per month of the same collection

Tags: javascript, meteor, momentjs, meteor-blaze

I have the collection of invoices, with the tax field, I must call the invoices for each month and calculate the total tax.

I have Momentjs add to meteor and uses blaze.

[App invoices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6trf4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search your collection for invoices created in a particular month like so:

```
var start = new Date(year, month, day);
var end = new Date(year, month, day);

//Invoices with a 'date' field between the 'start' and 'end' dates
var cursor = CollectionName.find({ date : { $gte : start, $lt: end });
```

You can then find the total of the tax fields:

```
var taxTotal = 0;
var results = cursor.forEach(function(doc) {
  //Adds the tax field of each document to the total
  taxTotal += doc.tax;
});
```

More information on the `forEach` method of a cursor can be found [here](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Cursor-forEach)