# how can i take the value of the month of the variable CreatedAt

Tags: mongodb, meteor, momentjs, meteor-blaze

I have the collection orders, and i want to take *month* and *year* of the variable "createdAt" ; i use momentsjs in the app.

```
Orders = new Mongo.Collection('orders');

Orders.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
  'taxtotal':{type:Number}, 
  'subtotal':{type:Number}, 



  createdAt:{
    type: Date,
    autoValue: function() {
       return new Date()
    }
  }, 

  createdBy: {
    type: String,
    autoValue: function() {
       return this.userId
    }
  }

}));
```

Comment: are you looking for labels to display to the user or values against which you can program?

Comment: hello, i need:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45464098/meteor-js-how-to-sum-records-per-month-of-the-same-collection/45464409#45464409

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try formatting the date using moment and just passing a 'month' or 'year' to to `format()`

Example:

```
var month = moment(createdAt).format('M');
var year  = moment(createdAt).format('YYYY');
```

Or you can use the built in functions to retrieve these values [DOCS](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/month/)

```
var month = moment(createdAt).month();
var year  = moment(createdAt).year();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is all!